# My Farfugium is Under Attack

Tags: diagnosis, pest-damage

One of my Farfugium seems to be slowly being eaten away. I know I have slugs in my garden on occasion, but have not seen evidence of other pests, but it's not clear to me if this is what slug damage looks like. I'll note there are no signs of mites/whatever on the underside or top of leaves, and that no other plant in that garden are seems to be suffering the same issues.   Any thoughts?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2dc5ix1avxi1ffw/2021-07-03%2008.54.46.jpg

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j2iqyn527g2pcph/2021-07-03%2008.54.52.jpg

https://www.dropbox.com/s/aunyda9mvsnxa1c/2021-07-03%2008.54.56.jpg

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9w8ft0w29u2c7yq/2021-07-03%2008.55.05.jpg

Comment: BTW, I'd like to embed these pics directly in the post, but they seem to be too big?

Comment: _"they seem to be too big?"_ -- they probably are. Please use a photo editing software of your choice to resize them. IIRC, the Stack Exchange image size limit is 2MB. You can reduce the dimensions of the photos (scaling them to a smaller size) and/or increase the compression (using a lower-quality JPEG setting) to achieve this. Stack Exchange questions are expected to be self-contained, not relying on third-party sites, so you definitely need to improve the question by formatting the photos in a site-compatible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some effort to bait and/or trap any snails/slugs went without much effect (or snails/slugs in trap) and noticing a relevant post on a local gardening site that indicated a cutter bee population in the area, I am generally convinced this is the issue I am having:

https://neilsperry.com/2021/07/question-of-the-week-number-1-july-8-2021/

I will have to figure out what to do to convince these guys to stop molesting my plants...not that they care about my plants that much.  Odd that this is the only plant in my garden experiencing the issue, though...at least that I've noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Had a look at the pics, and it just looks like slug or snail damage, though it doesn't look as if there's any slime trails; it looks as if whichever of those has been eating your plant seems to  have confined itself so far to the edges of the leaves. These  plants like damp soil and shadier conditions- that's an ideal environment for the slugs and snails too. I'd be putting a **small** amount of slug pellets down, but use whatever you prefer that keeps snails off. If you're unsure its slugs and snails, go out at night with a torch, especially on a damp night, and have a look...

Comment: Thanks...there are some slime trails in other nearby places like on the sidewalks, so if you think it looks like slug/snail damage (I wasn't sure what that specifically looked like until now), that's probably it.  I do have some slug pellet bait/killer, and have, on occasion in the past, set out a "beer trap", which I'll probably do again...far enough away to attract them away from their preferred area.